# Sending data from an Activity to WearableListenerService

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

When I read about communication between an `Activity` and `Service`, I found that we can use either

- IBinder
- Messenger
- AIDL

I am interested in the first two. So when I tried implementing this to communicate between an `Activity` and `WearableListenerService`, I needed to override the `onBind` function.

But then, I am getting a compiler error saying it

> **cannot override final method "onBind"**

I dont get such an error when I use a normal `Service`. So,

**1.** Does that mean we cannot use `IBinder` or `Messenger` approach to communicate with the `WearableListenerService` from an `Activity`?

**2.** If so, what is the next best way to pass message  to `WearableListenerService` from an `Activity` (or call a public method of that service from an Activity)?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/events.html

Comment: @pskink I am talking about sending data from an Activity to a 'WearableListenerService' (or triggering a public function in the 'WearableListenerService' from the Activity). But the Data Layer API examples in the link provides details of listening to the events of 'WearableListenerService' and not the other way

Comment: never played with it, but isn't `onMessageReceived()` for that?

Comment: @pskink The `onMessageReceived()` function receives data from other nodes (I suppose). In this case, The 'mobile' is having the 'Activity' and the 'WearableListenerService'. Both are on same node. I tried to send it anyways, but without any luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: no idea, but maybe this will help: http://android-wear-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/sync.html

Comment: I stumbled upon the same problem. And according to pskink's link, the localbroadcast receiver is the way to communicate between service and activity. This is also stated in the official documentation. Since you can use the googleApiClient from your activity to communicate between devices you shouldn't need to communicate from activity to service.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After some digging, I found the solution. Hope it helps somebody else.

We can send message from an Activity to `WearableListenerService` using `Wearable.MessageApi` functions.
When the `Activity` and `WearableListenerService` are on the same Node (device), we need to **get the instance of the local node** (current node from which the message is sent) for sending the message as below

```
NodeApi.GetLocalNodeResult nodes = Wearable.NodeApi.getLocalNode(mGoogleApiClient).await();
```

rather than

```
NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult nodes  = Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(mGoogleApiClient).await();
```

which is used to get the list of other devices (such as wear) connected to the phone.

So, I was able to successfully send a message from my Activity to WearableListenerService as follows

> Activity Code

```
public class PhoneActivity extends Activity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

    private static final String TAG = "PhoneActivity";

    public static final String CONFIG_START = "config/start";
    public static final String CONFIG_STOP= "config/stop"

    Intent intent;
    TextView txtview;

    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_phone);

        if(null == mGoogleApiClient) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(Wearable.API)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();
            Log.v(TAG, "GoogleApiClient created");
        }

        if(!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            Log.v(TAG, "Connecting to GoogleApiClient..");
        }

        startService(new Intent(this, PhoneService.class));
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        Log.v(TAG,"onConnectionSuspended called");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.v(TAG,"onConnectionFailed called");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        Log.v(TAG,"onConnected called");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.v(TAG, "onStart called");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.phone, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_start_) {
            new SendActivityPhoneMessage(CONFIG_START,"").start();
        }else if (id == R.id.action__stop) {
            new SendActivityPhoneMessage(CONFIG_STOP,"").start();
        }else if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    class SendActivityPhoneMessage extends Thread {
        String path;
        String message;

        // Constructor to send a message to the data layer
        SendActivityPhoneMessage(String p, String msg) {
            path = p;
            message = msg;
        }

        public void run() {
            NodeApi.GetLocalNodeResult nodes = Wearable.NodeApi.getLocalNode(mGoogleApiClient).await();
            Node node = nodes.getNode();
            Log.v(TAG, "Activity Node is : "+node.getId()+ " - " + node.getDisplayName());
            MessageApi.SendMessageResult result = Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(mGoogleApiClient, node.getId(), path, message.getBytes()).await();
            if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Activity Message: {" + message + "} sent to: " + node.getDisplayName());
            }
            else {
                // Log an error
                Log.v(TAG, "ERROR: failed to send Activity Message");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> **Service Code**

```
public class PhoneService extends WearableListenerService implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

    private static final String TAG = "PhoneService";

    public static final String CONFIG_START = "config/start";
    public static final String CONFIG_STOP = "config/stop";

    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    public PhoneService() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.v(TAG, "Created");

        if(null == mGoogleApiClient) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(Wearable.API)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();
            Log.v(TAG, "GoogleApiClient created");
        }

        if(!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            Log.v(TAG, "Connecting to GoogleApiClient..");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        Log.v(TAG, "Destroyed");

        if(null != mGoogleApiClient){
            if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
                mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
                Log.v(TAG, "GoogleApiClient disconnected");
            }
        }

        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        Log.v(TAG,"onConnectionSuspended called");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.v(TAG,"onConnectionFailed called");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        Log.v(TAG,"onConnected called");

    }

    @Override
    public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEvents) {
        super.onDataChanged(dataEvents);
        Log.v(TAG, "Data Changed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
        super.onMessageReceived(messageEvent);
        if(messageEvent.getPath().equals(CONFIG_START)){
            //do something here
        }else if(messageEvent.getPath().equals(CONFIG_STOP)){
            //do something here
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPeerConnected(Node peer) {
        super.onPeerConnected(peer);
        Log.v(TAG, "Peer Connected " + peer.getDisplayName());
    }

    @Override
    public void onPeerDisconnected(Node peer) {
        super.onPeerDisconnected(peer);
        Log.v(TAG, "Peer Disconnected " + peer.getDisplayName());
    }
}
```