# Binder for service extending WearableListenerService

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm developing android wear project with Service extends WearableListenerService.
When I'm trying to add Service binder I see this error

```
private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

 public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    DataLayerListenerService getService() {
        return DataLayerListenerService.this;
    }
 }

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
     return mBinder;
}


 Error:(196, 20) error: onBind(Intent) in DataLayerListenerService cannot override onBind(Intent) in WearableListenerService
overridden method is final
```

Is it possible to bind WearableListenerService somehow? How to pass data from  WearableListenerService to Activity without using broadcasts?

Answer (score 1):

You not have to use Bind.

You can communicate through mGoogleApiClient.

[Sending data from an Activity to WearableListenerService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26479193/sending-data-from-an-activity-to-wearablelistenerservice)

This Answer help your problem solve.