# Wearable MessageAPI onMessageReceived never hit, different devices id's

Tags: wear-os, android-wear-data-api

Trying to send a message from an emulated mobile device to an emulated wear device.  I'm able to pair the wear device through the Android Wear app and verify that `onPeerConnected` of the wear device is hit (`onMessageReceived` isn't).

Using two code versions to return `node.getId()` results in two different id's of the wear device.

Running this:

```
          new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    NodeApi.GetLocalNodeResult nodes = Wearable.NodeApi.getLocalNode(mGoogleApiClient).await();
                    Node node = nodes.getNode();
                    MessageApi.SendMessageResult result = Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(mGoogleApiClient, node.getId(), "Hello Watch 1", null).await();

                    if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                        Log.e(getPackageName(), "error");
                    } else {
                        Log.i(getPackageName(), "success!!!! sent to: " + node.getId());
                    }
                }
            }).start
```

returns: *08-09 10:24:33.106 17914-18007/com.wear.myapp I/com.wear.myapp: success!!!! sent to: **223faf0e***

Running this:

```
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult nodes = Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(mGoogleApiClient).await();

                    for (Node node : nodes.getNodes()) {
                        MessageApi.SendMessageResult result = Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(mGoogleApiClient, node.getId(), "Hello Watch 2", null).await();

                        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                            Log.e(getPackageName(), "error");
                        } else {
                            Log.i(getPackageName(), "success!!!! sent to: " + node.getId());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).start();
```

Returns: *08-09 10:24:33.108 17914-18006/com.wear.myapp I/com.wear.streamer: success!!!! sent to: **3a000c12***

Even stranger hardcoding in a fake Node ID for the wear device still returns a success message in the logs.  Feel like I'm getting a false positive result.

WearableListenerService:

```
            @Override
            public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
                Log.i(getPackageName(), "Message received");
            }


            @Override
            public void onPeerConnected(Node peer) {
                Log.i(getPackageName(), "Peer connected");
            }
```

I've read through every SO questions similar to this but haven't seen anyone mention different device id's.  I've triple-checked that the applicationIds and dependencies are identical between mobile and wear.

UPDATE:

If unpair the Wear emulator and run `Wearable.NodeApi.getLocalNode` I still get a nodeId returned, while `Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes` does not, which leads me to believe `getConnectedNodes` is what I should be using.

Also, shutting down the Wear emulator still returns a connected node id for `getLocalNode` which leads me to believe it's returning something other then the watch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, do not use deprecated methods like onPeerConnected.
Always use CapabilityApi methods instead. This is improtaint!

I've got a question. Which kind of Android Wear APK (on handheld) file are you using? Don't you know that modern versions of Android Wear APK are not useful? They doesn't work properly.

If you are using old version of API you have to understand that modern APIs such as CapabilityApi doesn't work.

Nowadays, this is not possible to make a stable connection between emulated Wearable and emulated Handheld. One of them have to be a real device.

The only solution that I can suggest is to test your application of real wearable and handheld devices.

Always use up-to-date GoogleServices library to test, use real devices, use not deprecated APIs.

Before publishing decrease GoogleServices library version in order to make your app workable for not updated devices.

In my practice, emulators work very strange.

Comment: I wasn't aware `onPeerConnected` was deprecated.  Usually Android Studio will display a message if an api is deprecated but it's not for `onPeerConnected`.  Unfortunately, the devices I own do not have the APIs I need yet, so I'm forced to use the emulator.  I'll look into the `CapabilityAPI`.  Thanks

Comment: If this helps anyone in the future, you can use the emulators to send messages from a phone to a wear device using the poorly documented `CapabilityApi`

Answer (score 0):

One possible issue could be the following: you are grabbing all connected nodes and then you grab the very first one to target for your message. That can very well end up being the cloud node (or another wearable device if you have multiple ones) and not your phone. The correct approach is to use the CapabilityApis to find the right node to send your message to. In your code, look at the node.toString() for the node that you selected to confirm that it is picking the cloud, to be sure that is the issue.

Check this related SO ticket:

- [OnMessageReceived not called in WearableListenerService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24957860/onmessagereceived-not-called-in-wearablelistenerservice)
- [onMessageReceived() never called, although connected to handheld](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29174571/onmessagereceived-never-called-although-connected-to-handheld)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm looking into the CapabilityApis per your post.  I ran across someone suggesting to make sure the same certificate is being used for each device, though I didn't think emulators needed to worry about certificates.

After more trial and error I'm thinking that `getConnectedNodes` is the correct method to use and it seems to be sending the message correctly but the wear app is not receiving it.